# sqlalchemy primary key without auto-increment

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to establish a table with a layout approximately like the following:

```
class Widget(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'widgets'
    ext_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    w_code = db.Column(db.String(34), unique=True)
    # other traits follow...
```

All field values are provided through an external system, and new Widgets are discovered and some of the omitted trait values may change over time (very gradually) but the ext_id and w_code are guaranteed to be unique.  Given the nature of the values for ext_id it behaves ideally as a primary key.

However when I create a new record, specifying the ext_id value, the value is not used in storage. Instead the values in ext_id follow an auto-increment behavior.

```
>>> # from a clean database
>>> skill = Widget(ext_id=7723, w_code=u'IGF35ac9')
>>> session.add(skill)
>>> session.commit()
>>> Skill.query.first().ext_id
1
>>>
```

How can I specify to SQLAlchemy that the ext_id field should be used as the primary key field without auto-increment?

Note: 
I could add an extra synthetic id column as the primary key and make ext_id be a unique column instead but this both complicates my code and adds a (minimal) extra bloat to the database and all I/O to it. I'm hoping to avoid that.

Issue originated from a larger project but I was able to create a smaller repro.

Testing with sqlite

Comment: What does your Widget.__init__ look like? I think I use the feature you need exactly in the way you seem to be using it and it works, provided I set the self.ext_id in contructor (or somewhere else).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Set [`autoincrement=False`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) to disable creating a sequence or serial for the primary key.

```
ext_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
```